# Programmatically update all WooCommerce prices (Variations)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a shop that i now want on another domain and for that reason i need to update all prices on the new domain. I need to multiply all prices by 1.45.

I've tried an code snippet, which actually works great on simple products, but it does not work on variable/variations product.

```
function return_custom_price($price, $product) {
    global $post, $blog_id;
    $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    $price = ($price*1.45);
    return $price;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'return_custom_price', 10, 2);
```

I want this code to also multiply variation pricing by 1.45

Comment: Do you need it to be changed in the database or just in the front-end?

Comment: @Screenload In theory both places, it's because it's located in another country, so the currency is different, and i don't want to use currency switcher or other plugins :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add this line below your code it **should** also do it for variations.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'return_custom_price', 10, 2);
```

Keep in mind that the database has still stored the "base"-price.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That actually works great. Now the problem is it still shows the old price in the front-end but with striked-out, so it almost shows the item on sale, so it shows the old price which is 19,00 and that is striked out and then it shows 27,55 beside it

Comment: Then you'd have to update the database directly and don't use any code. **Backup your database** and run this SQL-query: ```UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = meta_value*1.45 WHERE meta_key = '_price'```

Comment: This actually worked but again only on simple products, not variations. IS there another code i should use for variations?

Comment: Okay I forgot the other meta... try this as well: ```UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = meta_value*1.45 WHERE meta_key = '_regular_price'```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Works like a goddamn charm. Last thing. Do you know a quick fix for decimals? After multiplying i get a price that is 39,004999999999995 even though i added max 2 decimals in WooCommerce. Do you know a quickfix? :D

Comment: Nevermind, my bad. It is working perfectly. Sorry for the inconvience. Thanks!